# Спецификатор времени компиляции noexcept

Tags: c++

1. Ясно, что данная спецификация исключений  уменьшает размер
   итогового файла и ускоряет работу программы,  выражает, что в
   функции не генерируется исключение, иначе программа аварийно
   завершится. Ясно как и когда использовать...
2. Ясно, что  `noexcept(expression)` вернет  `true` если выражение
   помечено как `noexcept` и `false` _ в обратном случаи...

А  для чего нужны спецификации исключения   `noexcept(true)`  и `noexcept(false)`, как и когда они используются?..

Comment: Здесь можно почитать: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В зависимотсти от того, где находится `noexcept( ... )`, он может имеет два разных назначения. Одно вы назвали (проверка выражения на `noexcept`-ность), а вот второе:

```
void func() noexcept(условие) {...}
```

Здесь, `func` будет являться `noexcept` только если условие истинно.

`noexcept(true)` эквивалентен `noexcept`, поэтому редко используется.

`noexcept(false)` обычно эквивалентен отсутствию `noexcept`, с одним исключением:

Если функция является `noexcept` по умолчанию (например, любой деструктор), то `noexcept(false)` позволяет сделать ее не `noexcept`.

---

Еще, иногда можно увидеть вот такую запись:

```
void func() noexcept(noexcept(выражение)) {...}
```

Здесь функция станет `noexcept`, только если указанное выражение является `noexcept`.

Comment: говорят, что  noexcept(true) не совсем эквивалентен noexcept, в случаи, если в функции все таки сгенерировано исключение....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А кто говорит? Вон по ссылке в комментах написано, что *"`noexcept` - Same as `noexcept ( true )`."*

Comment: "noexcept(false) позволяет сделать ее не noexcept." Тогда какой смысль в нем, если и без его указания  функция не   noexcept?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Не всегда. Некоторые функции (как минимум деструкторы) по умолчанию `noexcept`.

Comment: _`noexcept(noexcept(выражение))`_ - почему `noexcept` дважды?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, особенно если написать `#define true false`?)))

Comment: @Qwertiy Внутренний `noexcept` проверяет выражение на `noexcept`-ность и возвращает true или false.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, понял.  А что можно использовать в выражении? Аргументы можно, например?

Comment: @Qwertiy Выражение должно быть `constexpr`, поэтому так точно нельзя: `void foo(bool x) noexcept(x)`. По идее, любое constexpr выражение подходит.

Comment: @Qwertiy,   точно, можно и так нагадить..:))

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, тогда как-то странно. Кстати, разве constexpr имеет право кидать исключения? Вроде бы это UB?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не может, это ошибка. В `void foo() noexcept(X)` дело не в том, кидает ли Х исключения, а в том, чему равно значение Х: true или false. Если вопрос был, можно ли написать `void foo(MyClass c) noexcept(noexcept(c.bar()))` - то да, можно, потому что внутренний noexcept в любом случае constexpr.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ты же сказал что внутренний noexcept проверяет, кидает ли выражение исключение. При этом выражение должно быть constexpr, а значит оно его не кидает. Или constexpr'ом должно быть выражение, переданное во внешний? Тогда остаётся вопрос, что можно передать во внутренний. Если аргументом является функция, которая кидает исключение, а я собираюсь её вызывать, то что?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не, стоп. В `void foo() noexcept(noexcept(X))` можно передать что угодно. В `void foo() noexcept(Y)` можно передать только constexpr выражение.

Comment: `void doSmth(void (*f)()) noexcept { f(); }` - если функция `f` бросает исключение, то этот код корректен или нет? Нсли нет, то можно ли сделать `noexcept(noexcept(f()))`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Корректен, но бросание исключения вызовет `std::terminate` (можно было бы даже написать в теле функции throw, компилятор дал бы максимум варнинг). А `noexcept(f())` вернет `true`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101618/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-holyblackcat).

Answer (score 0):

Функции:

```
 void foo() noexcept(true); 
 void foo() noexcept(false);
```

— являются функции с разными типами (не могут формировать перегруженный набор). Это позволяет, например, интерфейсу приложения требовать `callback`_и, которые (не) выбрасывают исключений